# Issue rendering local static image in iOS only (React Native)

Tags: ios, image, react-native

I'm new to coding and react native, so sorry if this is a stupid question.

I'm having issues rendering a hamburger icon from the following code. It works as expected on Android but not iOS.

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, TouchableOpacity, Image } from 'react-native';
import { totalPoints, totalBucks } from '../datasets/UserData.js';

export class Navbar extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
    }

    burgerPress = value => {
        this.props.onPress();
       }

render(){
var points = totalPoints;
var bucks = totalBucks;

    return(
        <View style={styles.row}>
            <Text style={styles.column} />
            <Text style={styles.column}>
                <Image source={require('../../assets/coins.png')}  style={{ width: 30, height: 30, resizeMode: 'contain'}}/> 
                 {"  "}{ points }
            </Text> 
            <Text style={styles.column}>
                <Image source={require('../../assets/bills.png')}   style={{ width: 40, height: 40, resizeMode: 'contain'}}/> 
                {"  "}{ bucks }
            </Text>
            <View style={styles.column}>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.burgerPress()} style={{width: 40, height: 40, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center'}}>
                <Image source={require('../../assets/hamburger.png')} resizeMode={'contain'} style={{ width: 40, height: 40, backgroundColor: 'lightblue', tintColor: '#ffffff',  justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center'}}/> 
            </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
        </View>
        );
};
};

const styles={
    row: {
        flex: 1,
        alignItems: 'flex-end',
        flexDirection: 'row',
        borderBottomWidth: 1,
        borderColor: "#000000",
        padding: 5,
        justifyContent: 'center'
    },
    column: {
        flex: 1,
        alignItems: 'center',
        flexDirection: 'column',
        justifyContent: 'center'
    }
}
```

The coins and bills icons load properly on both platforms. The hamburger loads on android, but on iOS, all I get is the background color. If I delete the backgroundColor and tintColor, it renders nothing, so I think the issue is that it is not importing the image at all but only on iOS. Is there any way to get this to work?

[iOS display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tf8p2.png)(unexpected)

[Android display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NYjgj.png)(expected)

Answer (score 0):

I don't see what your `styles.column` are specified as but as a test I would give your `TouchableOpacity` a width and height as well.  Then try to set `justifyContent: center` and `alignItems: center` to make sure the image is not being hidden for some reason.

You might also need to specify the `resizeMode={'contain'}` prop in Image rather than just declaring it in your image style.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I updated the code above to show the styles and the suggested edits. It's still showing the same issue....works on Android, not iOS

Comment: Definitely interesting... I just copy and pasted your code into one of my screen components and it showed perfectly.  Can you just show your entire component top to bottom.  Also are you using vanilla RN or using Expo with it.

Comment: The entire component is in the edit above now. I am using Expo to render on my android phone, on an iPad, in the browser and in a iOS emulator. It works in the browser and on my Android phone but not on the iPad or iOS emulator.

Comment: I got it to work by using a smaller png icon file, so it must have had something to do with resizing. It resized in Android but not iOS. Definitely a weird issue, but glad it's fixed. Thank you for your help!